# Debug Ionic 3 app on mac while using ios emulator

Tags: typescript, debugging, ionic-framework, safari

I am trying to debug ionic 3 typescript files on safari developer tools. I have enabled emulate and can detect emulator on safari.

I have pages and components file in my project but I can't figure out where are these files as shown in image below.

[image]

Here I can only find js files in Resource and Debugger Tab. Any files related to dependency packages or libraries. Can't find files that I created myself. Just following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXzezPHUhUM

Answer (score 3):

You can use safari to debug app on emulator. Run your app and open Safari. In Develop tab you will find your emulator name. After selecting the name, you will be redirected to debug window where you can see your resources and watch network calls. Also, html elements can be inspected.

For more information go through the following link:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Answer (score 1):

1 . Enable "web inspector" on your iOS device.
    - Open "Settings" on your iOS device
    - Choose "Safari"
    - Choose "Advanced"
    - Set the "Web Inspector" button to "on" (make it green)

2. Enable "device debug" in Safari on your Mac

   - Select "Preferences" from the Safari menu
   - Choose the "Advanced" tab
   - Check the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" option (as shown in the image below)

     3. select "Develop" from the Safari menu
     4. select the "name of the attached device"
     5. select the "name of the app to be debugged"
     6. select "index.html"

   Now you can debug there.